# Is there a python-based utility for testing examples in comments

Tags: python, testing

Is there a python-based utility for testing examples in function comments? For example, given the following code in orwell_1984.py:

```
def two_plus_two():
    """Returns 2 + 2 according to Orwell's 1984"""
    # EX: two_plus_two() => 5
    return 5
```

The utility would do the equivalent of the following:

```
import orwell_1984
verify_test(orwell_1984.two_plus_two, (), 5)
```

where verify_test invokes the passed-in function with the specified parameters, and then makes sure equal to the expected value.

A while back I wrote something to do this in perl; see http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~tomohara/useful-scripts/test-perl-examples.perl. Before trying to port that, I am hoping to find a python-based utility that does something similar.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html

Comment: Not in comment but in doc strings: https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html

Answer (score 2):

That's called docstring in Python e.g.:

```
def two_plus_two():
    """Returns 2 + 2 according to Orwell's 1984.

    >>> two_plus_two()
    5
    """
    return 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import doctest
   doctest.testmod()
```

Check information about [`doctest` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent facility but not quite what I'm looking for. The main issue is the time it takes to create multi-lint comments versus a simple one liner.